# Fill remaining area with color?

Tags: css

[image: http://imgur.com/99X4x.jpg]

Above is a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried setting `height:100%`, but I get an "overflow" caused by having `margin-top:48px`, causing me to scroll down even though the content fits on 1 screen. 
Right now the content is only up to the colored part (I edited it out for clarity).

It's CSS is:

```
#main_area {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.sidebar { /* this one here */
    float: left;
    left: 10px;
    width: 278px;
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, floated DIV's are not a good solution for what you're trying to achieve - this is one of those situations where you're going to have to revert to using a multi-column TABLE or get funky with Javascript.

Remember - when you float a DIV, it is essentially removed from the page flow layout and is floated over the page's contents. Setting the height to 100% won't set the height of your column to the height of the page it floats over - it sets the height of the floated DIV to the combined height of the floated DIV's contents.

There's a pretty good description of this in "Head First HTML" from O'Reilly.

To be honest, if you want to create really controllable multi-column page designs, TABLEs are likely to be your best bet.

Comment: @bitcraze , i don't completly agree with your table approach , we can achieve the same with divs also. Now adays people are moving towards divs as they are more cleaner and even bots can search better.

Comment: Thanks. What about `position: absolute;`?

Comment: @john2x when you give an element position :absolute ,it doesn't flow with other elements in the page. It stays whereever you mentioend from top , left... if you say top:0px, left:0px and give as position absolute it always maintains in the top left corner.

Comment: @john2x , still i am unable to get what you are trying to achive , if you can tell very clearly we can easily implement.

Comment: @gov: Divs cannot do 100% height because 100% height in CSS means something completely different. As mentioned by bitcrazed, you either use javascript to figure out the px height and set the height of the div on every window resize or the simpler approach is use tables where 100% height means exactly what most people expect.

Comment: @gov so that means it won't center on the window right? how should I approach this using divs? EDIT: @slebetman Thanks. Javascript it is then.

Comment: @gov right now, `background-color` only fills up the part where there is content. I want it to fill the entire vertical area of the <div>, from top to bottom.

Comment: @john2x if you want to occupy the color , you can fixed height and background-color right.

Comment: @john2x see my updated answer , you can caclute the width and height based on screen and set them.

Comment: @gov sorry, I don't understand completely. I can't set a fixed height since I want to fill the entire window's height. EDIT: Ah thanks for that. So Javascript really is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I find something wrong with below css ,can you fix this first.

you gave left as 10px , but didn't mention as absolute , do you want this as absolute..??

and from the screenshot , i didn't get what exactly you want  can you explain it more

```
  .sidebar { /* this one here */
        float: left;
        left: 10px;
        width: 278px;
        padding-top: 48px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF
    }
```

do the below code in window resize event

```
var docHeight = Math.max(
            $(document).height(),
            $(window).height(),
            /* For opera: */
            document.documentElement.clientHeight
        );
        var docWidth = Math.max(
            $(document).width(),
            $(window).width(),
            /* For opera: */
            document.documentElement.clientWidth
        );
        $("#yourdiv").css({
            "height":docHeight,
            "width":docWidth
        });                   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I must've left it there. I'm trying to fill up the bottom part with red, just like the upper part. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: I tried your code. I placed it in a `$(window).onresize();`. It doesn't seem to do anything. I'm new to javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never. Thought this might help:

The htmls

```
<div id="content"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

The csss

```
#content { background-color: #F1EBD9; }
#left { float: left; width: 14em; }
#right { margin-left: 14em; background-color: #FFF; }
```

You can view this @ https://github.com/gutierrezalex/two-column-layout